# Print-Button on expose

Tags: buttons, position, printing

I have been thinking and thinking and thinking about this topic. I've researched multiple sources and theories. None of these was near to what we do, probably because of the pretty unique german regulations for the real-estate industry.

Our target group is pretty versatile but also includes a good amount of 60+ people. We recently switched from classical PDF exposes to a digital, automatic, version. We designed the print media query, as granting access to a static version is mandatory for legal reasons. That didn't help a lot because the older target groups are still asking for a printed version, so we are planning on putting a print button for them.

The question I am asking now is, where to put it?
Maybe some of you have some ideas or tipps. Preferably with a explanation of "why".

[image]

This is how the landing-view looks like. My idea would be, to put the print button below the object ID or below the price. What do you think or what position would you recommend?

Hint: the top right is reserved for a new "status" function.

Comment: Is your 60+ age group going to know what to do with a PDF once they open it? Is printing wirelessly from a mobile device common in your region, or is this mainly to address the legal aspects?

Comment: We are handling it in two ways, if a PDF is attached (buyable objects) to the object in our CRM, we are attaching it as download, if there is no PDF (rentable objects), we are prompting the print function (which is, what most of the 60+ customers have asked for). Wireless printing is a pretty common thing over here (currently), as our elders "love" to print everything they can, which reflects in our lawmaking (sadly). It is a mix of our users request and legal requirements. The function, anyhow, is also implanted in our desktop view, too.

Comment: Good to hear. Sounds like a good feature for your target users. Mainly just wondering because many users I know would likely just take a screenshot of the PDF with their phone...

Comment: I wish our users would know how to take a screenshot ;) Out of experience I can tell you they rather take a photo of their screen, calling it "screenshot" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got inspired by [this answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/125837/98561) however I object with the placement of the button. In my opinion it should be placed on the right-hand side of the screen, like this:

[image]

**Why on the right-hand side**, one may ask? From the layout I assume the target device is a handheld (smartphone) type.
The facts are that somewhere between 70% and 95% of the humanity is right handed, some research backing it up:

- Holder, M. K. (1997). "[Why are more people right-handed?](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=why-are-more-people-right)". Scientific American. Retrieved 2008-04-14.
- Hardyck C, Petrinovich LF (1977). "Left-handedness". Psychol Bull. 84 (3): 385–404. doi:[10.1037/0033-2909.84.3.385](https://doi.org/10.1037%2F0033-2909.84.3.385). PMID [859955](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/859955)

This means that the majority of your target group is using their devices in the following way:

- they hold it in their right hand and use their thumb to navigate (slide and tap)
- they hold it firmly in their left hand and use their right hand's index finger to navigate

If the action button is on the right, it can respectively be:

- easily reached with the thumb
- tapped with the index finger without obscuring the screen with the right hand

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will read into the sources you've attached and will come back with additional questions and/or a acceptance of the answer as soon as possible. :)

Comment: @marvinpoo - the sources are mentioned to back up the number of right-handed people and not for button placement.

Comment: yes, I've noticed. Still a important decision. (atleast or us). But it is also backed up by our tap statistics and mouse-movement statistics. Also perfectly fits fine in the future development plans of the expose for us. (Not to mention the perfect fit for the Gutenberg Diagram, as this would be the "end region")

Thanks for the tipp, Mike! Answer accepted :)

Comment: I completely agree with Mike's suggestion, but unless we know the width of the price fields, it is hard for anyone to guess if that button will fit on the right side. There will probably be a 10 digit value and the currency unit. To be on the safer side, I will still put the button at the bottom but adequately above the fold. To increase accessibility with both right and left hand users, the button can cover the entire width of the screen.

Comment: @Ren - $Obj_buyprice is 13 characters long and still not occupying all available space. Furthermore, the button does not need to be that wide - it can be more of a rectangular shape (narrower and taller).

Comment: I agree to be in the right hand too, but my concern is if the two added points beside the button became bigger, so in order to avoid wrapping I think to keep it right but put it in a separate line so shift it to the bottom right.

Comment: @conversation - We have our preset stylesets which define our buttons. The prices can vary from three digits + decimal (legal requirement) to six digits + decimal. This is how it looks like in our dev enviroment: https://i.imgur.com/YIjjDs5.jpg - we generally do not design for any devices below 370px width (only 2 visitors in over 1 1/2 years so far)

Answer (score 2):

Download or Print whichever works better.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another option it worth to think of and try it, is to include a floating download button, it will remain all the way and it will take action for the screen you swipe to it.

The floating button now became a used behavior even in IOS.

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the idea. That might could be a feature in the furure, but we have created a strictly set styleguide for interaction elements due to brand recognition, which wouldn't allow us, for now, to implant floating objects that are not navigational (bottom nav / back-to-top button).